# Is SessionHandler::gc()'s $maxlifetime argument passed automatically on internal execution?

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

When implementing my own session handler can I be sure that a $maxlifetime argument corresponding to the PHPRC's `gc_maxlifetimevalue` will always be passed to its `gc()` method if it's called internally?

As an example, could this happen:

```
 // Set before a session is started.
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60);


 // GC is called by session_start() based on probability settings.
public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    // $maxlifetime has no value
```

or do I need to implement a value check/set a default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be passed automatically.

There's no reason to think otherwise.

Comment: As it's not stated in the docs, I found no firm answer anywhere else, and I've seen a few popular frameworks set a default argument value in the method declaration in their handlers I figured there was reason enough.

Comment: You're just trying to read between the lines too hard ... The docs show you the `SessionHandlerInterface`, which declares `gc()` with this parameter, exactly so that PHP can know how to pass it to you. In case you're wondering, I can confirm this from experience. :)

Comment: I think you're right - if I'd been thinking about it properly I'd have tested it out by setting the gc's probability settings to always trigger. Thanks again for the answer.